# Automatic Directors grid list using Plugins

Tags: wordpress

I added my directors list manually in a WordPress page

[image]

my question is there is any other way to add my directors list automatically using a plugin or some other ways.

Correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom post type called Directors and then create a new post for each Director and also have the option to add any relevant information using custom fields.
Then you could use an archive page to run a new WP_Query that lists the Directors in an order that you want.

Answer (score 0):

Find a way..
this Works fine....

[image]